# Manhwa with a blonde girl fighting a black-haired guy

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manhwa which is believe is newly published.
There is a black haired guy, he seems to be injured. There is also a blonde haired girl who seems to be fighting with him.

I saw it on [a TikTok video](https://vm.tiktok.com/ZMFyMDtoF/) with some panels from the comic.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I changed my comment a bit, I don‘t know if this Manhwa is about fighting, but there was a short Fight-scene so I assume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *[Monsters](https://dreamfactorystudio.co.kr/conlist06.php)* (AKA *요괴*) by Dream Factory Studio.

> The Monster’s blood in his vein exploded when he woke from death!
> Monsters that existed only in fairy tales appear in the middle of a
> city in the 21st century, break down buildings and harm humans. A
> group of humans with extraordinary abilities against them! The story
> of Naro, an outcast boy who fights against monsters.

[image]

The serial is currently receiving an English translation, so you should be able to read it fairly shortly, or you can find the original Korean version online [here](https://page.kakao.com/content/60524866).